# 404 Error on Zapier and AWS: Webflow --> Zapier --> Webhook --> API Gateway --> Lambda

Tags: webhooks, zapier, webflow

here is was my initial attempt at workflow:

Webflow form --> API Gatway --> Lambda --> S3.

Webflow doesn't encode form data as json on url, so I am now trying to make the following work:

Webflow form --> Zapier --> Webhook (encode json) --> API Gatway --> Lambda (parse json) --> S3

I already have the AWS backend set up. Connecting the front end is the current hangup. Is there a better way? If zapier/webhook can encode the json I am open to that but I'm getting 404 error messages when I try to take even simple key and value data from the form and encode it with webhook inside zapier. Any help appreciated

I started with a post action for zapier with a webflow trigger, webhook action to try to encode (select json) and I place the key and value into the webhook. That gave me errors on the test and doesn't trigger labmda in AWS. So I went back and set up a webhook 'custom request' post form but stil no luck.

from Cloudwatch:
[ERROR] KeyError: 'body'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 53, in lambda_handler
try: body = json.loads(event['body'])
[ERROR] KeyError: 'body' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 53, in lambda_handler     try: body = json.loads(event['body'])